# ASP.NET MVC 4: Skip Validation in Child Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

First of all, sorry about my English. Not my natural language.

I have a class named `Category` like the code below. Note that in this code I also have a `Category` property, in which I can reference a father Category. It's just the same class declared inside the class. Like Inception. So, this Father Category object has the same properties of "the class that declared him."

The property `Name` is Required. Remember this property.

```
public class Category
{
    public int? Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Father Category")] //NOT REQUIRED
    public Category Father { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] //REMEMBER THIS REQUIRED PROPERTY!!
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

That's my Class.

So, in the Category View, I can do something like this:

Note: `CompleteEditorFor` and `CompleteDropDownListFor` are extended methods which add some extra html in each field, just for adjusting the layout.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.CompleteEditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.CompleteEditorFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.CompleteEditorFor(x => x.Status)

    @Html.CompleteDropDownListFor(x => x.Father.Id, ViewData["Categories"], "Id", "Name", "Select...")

    @Html.SubmitButton()
}
```

The code above runs just fine.

Now there's the problem:

When I click the Save button, it makes a `HttpPost`, and this is the `Action` for that:

(The code below has some modified message strings and extended methods.)
(`CategoriesBLL` is the class that gets the categories from Database.)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(Category item)
    {
        ViewData.Add("Categories", CategoriesBLL.select());
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)//PROBLEM IS HERE!!!!!!!!!
            {
                if (CategoryBLL.insert(item) != 0)
                {

                    ViewData.AddSuccess("Some Success Message");


                    return View(new Category());
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddError("Some error message");
                    return View(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddError("Some SERIOUS error message");
                return View(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddError("Some EVEN MORE SERIOUS message");
            return View(item);
        }

    }
```

The problem is at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` line.

Why?

Because my `Category` class has a required property called `Name`. I don't need this property to do what I'm doing, I just need the `Id` of the `Father` property. I can get this `Id` in this line on the View:

```
@Html.CompleteDropDownListFor(x => x.Father.Id, ViewData["Categories"], "Id", "Name", "Select...")
```

And that works.

But the `Name` property is `null`, and is Required, but it's only Required when I'm informing the Child class. Not the Father class.

I don't even know how to search for it on Google or StackOverflow...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried to remove the child entities before validating or not posting them with the form?

Comment: I need to post the father entity, but I just need 1 property, the Id property. Name is also required but not in this father entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [View Models](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/). Your view model should contain all the fields that you need on the view, minus Father property. Then in your controller you'll need to map view model to your model. You can easily do this with [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). (However, direct mapping from view to domain model is not recommended, but that you'll sort out later)

I know, at first this might look like a drag, but trust me. Your view is not the same as your domain model. Next thing you'll know, you'll need some sort of drop-down on your view and some other extra checkbox that you don't have in your domain model. Also, if you use view model, your security will be improved. I'll get you some info about that if interested.

Comment: Security Improvement? I'm interested!

Comment: Read this http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/aspnet-mvc-model-binding-security  First 2 paragraphs will tell you what can go wrong. The rest of the article is recommended to read as well. I have seen a video with Troy Hunt where he elaborated in details about that, but can't find it now -(

Comment: Yeah, if your project is short-lived and not going to be developed in the future, then switching everything to the view models might not be worth it. Yes, you can email me: trailmax1 at gmail dot com. I'll try answering your questions.

Comment: Actually i've tried to implement view models, now it's working fine! Doesn't take much time, and Automapper is cool :D

Comment: 4 years later, this is still very valuable. However, that link is not working anymore. So here's the new one: http://codetunnel.io/aspnet-mvc-model-binding-security/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making the class IValidatableObject interface on your model instead of property decorators.  If you really want to use a property decorator then you might hav eto right a custom one.

Comment: Will it change the way I validate this model, or the ModelState validator will automatically know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Category : IValidatableObject
{
    public int? Id{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Father Category")] //NOT REQUIRED
    public Category Father { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")] //REMEMBER THIS REQUIRED PROPERTY!!
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (this.Enable)
        {
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Name ,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Name" },
                results);
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Status,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Status" },
                results);
        }
        return results;
    }
}

public void Validate()
{
        var toValidate = new Category()
        {
            Name = "Just a name",
            Status = true
        };

        bool validateAllProperties = false;

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
            toValidate,
            new ValidationContext(toValidate, null, null),
            results,
            validateAllProperties);
}
```

Comment: no, you don't. Controller MVC stack checks for IValidatableObject automatically and executes the validation for you.

Comment: @IamStalker what's with `public void Validate()` outside of the class? Should it be inside of the class? if inside of the class, I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: I think this method is just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
ModelState.Remove("PropertyNameInModel");
```

or

```
ModelState.Remove<ViewModel>(x => x.SomeProperty);
```